# How to change label's content in an user control from void in a class WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, user-controls, wpf-controls

I'm looking a method for changing content of a label in User Control from class.

If it was page, I updating label's content from class with

```
var main = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
main.PageTransitionControl.ShowPage(new LoginControl());
```

But I couldn't convert it to for user control.

The lite question is how can I update a label's content from a class.
The label in an User Control .xaml...

Thanks for advance

---- **Edit:**

**The Label:**

```
<Label x:Name="Test1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404"/>
```

Comment: Have you used `DataBinding` anywhere in your XAML?

Comment: can you show us the XAML for context?

Comment: editted the question. and added xaml code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

what  you  need is public  method  like this

```
 /// </summary>
    public partial class LoginControl : UserControl
    {
        public LoginControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public string SetMyLabel(string text)
        {
            Test1.Content = text;  
        }
    }
```

and you can set  the text

```
       var main = App.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;
        LoginControl log = new LoginControl();  
        main.PageTransitionControl.ShowPage(log);
        log.SetMyLabel("YourText");
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a property to the label content and assign the value to that property from your class

```
private string _labelname;
public string labelname
{
    get
    { 
        return _labelname;
    }

    set
    {
       _labelname=value;
        OnPropertyChanged("labelname");
    }
}
```

In you XAML

```
<Label x:Name="Test1" Content="{Binding labelname}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="404"/>
```

You can then assign a value to `labelname` property from your class like this

```
labelname="New Label";
```

Edit: Implement this method in your class

```
 public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
     PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     {
         handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
     }
  }
```

Comment: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs'
on this line "OnPropertyChanged("labelname");"

Comment: @ErçinDedeoğlu Can you post the implementation of your `"OnPropertyChanged` method